# Different code for different iOS version is still showing a warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, xcode7

I'm trying to clear all the warnings of my App since the update to iOS 9.0 and I'm trying to do this:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_9_0
// less than iOS 9.0
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
}
#else
// iOS 9.0 or later
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
}
#endif
```

But I'm still getting all the warnings, I'm doing something wrong?

I have discover that this instruction is not working correctly in iOS 8.0 and iOS 7.0.

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {} not work in iOS 9.0 .

So ,you have to use - (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations. It is working in all iOS Version.

Don't check iOS version. simply use only
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations method for all iOS version.

Answer (score -2):

Your #if code and #else code are identical. So what do you expect?

Comment: They are not identical. The return type is different.